# Run SQL Queries In the same Order as They were Generated

Tags: laravel, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I have two ECS tasks connecting to the same RDS instance. Those two ECS tasks are updating the same RDS database in parallel. Please see the below illustration. (The two ECS tasks are 'Engine' and 'UI')

[image: RDS+Engine+UI+Tasks]

The lines inside the boxes represent database update queries. For this question, let's consider the queries marked as bold red lines. Suppose that UI node updated the database at 11.49. and the same record was updated by Engine node at 11.54. I expect these database update operations to execute on the database in the order they generated (as shown in the illustration).

As you can see in the illustration, the Engine node has frequent database updates whereas UI node database updates are rare.

The issue I'm facing is UI node database updates are delayed than Engine node database updates. **How can I make sure queries/updates are executed in the order they are generated?**

## What I have tried

I tried to delay the Engine query by 10 seconds. But still it gets executed first.

## Notes

- If the time difference between 2 *(red+bold)* queries are more than 30 seconds, they executed in the order they were generated.
- There is a third node (ECS task) which dispatches Laravel jobs to an SQS queue. Engine node is consuming those jobs and do the work.

Comment: *"How can I make sure queries/updates are executed in the order they are generated?"* - is it ok to assume execution time of a query instead of enforcing the atomicity using transaction of some sort?

Comment: @BagusTesa _regarding 'assume':_ in the next line of code after the query (in both Engine and UI), I log the time and the query details. (I got 11.49 and 11.54 from the logs). But when I inspect the database, the 11.49 query had overwritten the 11.54 query.

Comment: _regarding 'atomicity':_ the transactions are generated 5 seconds apart. I thought `atomicity` will not help in this situation. I'll check/research again. Thanks for the comment. @BagusTesa

Comment: are the 11.49 and 11.54 start time or finish time? if its the start time, then finishing later it is possible for it to replace any prior updates, but idk how amazon rds handles things like this.

Comment: those timestamps were logged from the app nodes (not from the database). I'll enable RDS 'server_audit_logs' for that cluster now _(Then I can see the queries on CloudWatch audit log group)_. Then we can get the exact times when and how those queries were executed.

Comment: i worked with cluster stuff ages ago and i remember that relying on timing for data consistency often misled conclusion especially on system that doesn't rely on timing itself, even worse it relies on eventual consistency. which is why i suggest to find something akin to transaction to ensure a strong consistency - so you wont mess on "dirty" data. it will have some performance penalty unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for providing a direction/suggestion. i'll try it. (i might need to research/understand further about transactions/consistency.)

Comment: it would be better if you could raise this particular issue to aws support. they have better view of the stuff under the hood.